# Coq use refine with bi-implication

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm not sure how to word my question, because I'm new to coq. I want to use refine with a theorem that includes bi-implication. Example code:

```
Parameters A B C : Prop.

Theorem t1:
  A -> B -> C.
Admitted.

Theorem t2:
  A -> B <-> C.
Admitted.

Theorem test1:
  A -> B -> C.
Proof.
  intros.
  refine (t1 _ _).
  assumption.
  assumption.
Qed.

Theorem test2:
  A -> B -> C.
Proof.
  intros A B.
  refine (t2 _ _).
```

t1 and t2 are theorems I want to use in refine. t1 works how i expect (shown in test1). But i have a problem with t2. The error I get is:

```
Ltac call to "refine (uconstr)" failed.
Error: Illegal application (Non-functional construction): 
The expression "t2 ?a" of type "Top.B <-> C"
cannot be applied to the term
 "?y" : "?T"
Not in proof mode.
```

What I have tried is something like this:

```
Theorem test3:
  A -> B -> C.
Proof.
  intros.
  cut (B <-> C).
  firstorder.
  refine (t2 _).
  assumption.
Qed.
```

But with longer props and proofs, it becomes a bit messy. (Also I have to prove the bi-implication myself). Can I use t2 and get its subgoals in a simpler way?

Thanks

Comment: In this case, you could just `apply t2`.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm trying to use a more complex theorem, just wanted to post a simple example.

Comment: if you do `destruct (t2 A).` you will get `H: B->C` and `H1: C->B` in the context. Then you can use `H` to solve your goal.  And the reason you can't use `refine (t2 _ _)` is that `t2` is of type `A->(B<->C)`, notice the parentheses.

Comment: Yeah that worked for me

Comment: I was hoping for maybe some smart tactic that is able to use B<->C to prove B->C and use it in refine somehow

Comment: `tauto.` can solve tautologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A <-> B` is defined as `(A -> B) /\ (B -> A)` so you can project with `proj1`, `proj2`:

```
Theorem test2:
  A -> B -> C.
Proof.
  intros A B.
  refine (proj1 (t2 _) _).
```

Comment: perfect, exactly what i was imagining